# @FeignClient always timeout when using eureka service id

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a spring-boot app which uses Declarative Feign Client

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@FeignClient(name = "${service-registry-name}", fallbackFactory = MyFallbackFactory.class, configuration = CommonFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface MyClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/test/reference/data")
    HttpEntity<String> getAllData();}
```

I have following application.yml

```
feign:
  okhttp:
    enabled: true

feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true

hystrix:
  command:
    MyClient#getAllData():
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false


logging:
  level:
    project:
      user:
        MyClient: DEBUG

feign:
  client:
    config:
      feign-name:
        requestInterceptors: com.test.MyRequestHeaderProcessor
```

This spring-boot app works perfectly fine and when I debug the I could see that the timeout value of 30000 is properly applied.

The trouble starts when I use this code NOT as a standalone spring boot app but as a dependency jar into another project.

At this time, the timeout is always 1000, which is the default. I managed to override this as well. But despite of that, i get HystrixRunTimeException, Timeout with null.

I have feign.hystrix.enabled=true.

If I use feign.hystrix.enabled=false, I can see that my request doesnt time out but then the Fallback mechanism fails to work.

But, when I add URL attribute in FeignClient it works fine and does NOT timeout.I cannot rely on the URL attribute as this is coming from the cloud foundry service URL which can change.

Comment: I added the URL attribute to the @FeignClient and now I don not get the Timeout issue. But this is a bad workaround for me as the URL is the CloudFoundy service URL which is subjected to change. So, now my problem statement also includes, why FeignClient timesout when I use service-id name (eureka service registry) but does NOT timeout when I add URL?????

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties in Application.yml file.

```
feign:
  client: 
    config: 
      default:
         connectTimeout: 80000000
         readTimeout: 80000000
```